# Flutter Web Persian/Arabic Strings Not Showing Properly on the UI

Tags: flutter, web, arabic, farsi

I just started to migrate to Flutter web and just at the start point, encountered this strange problem.
When using Persian/Arabic Characters in code, it would be shown improperly on the UI. Other Characters are shown nice.

Flutter Default Sample App

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Code:

```
 children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pressed the button this many times:',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              'شما این دکمه را این تعداد بار فشار داده اید:',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              'ñĚĖĎÆß',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
```

The Project and System Encoding are set to UTF-8.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine on dartpad https://dartpad.dev/1904b824b83992867a0778a5a95f17f1?

Are you setting some wrong page encoding it must be utf-8

Comment: Yes, your dartpad is working well but on the Android Studio and local web browser, it shows strange characters. All encodings for project and system are set to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the style in arabic text

```
Text(
 'شما این دکمه را این تعداد بار فشار داده اید:',          
),
```

their is fontwidth in style is the problem you getting error ( [][][][] )